# Paste Ctrl+C to "Open file" dialog

Tags: desktop-environments

[Windows "Open file" window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcqcp.png)

Windows had amazing feature of pasting an image from clipboard directly to "Open file" window when you try to upload something.

Is it possible on Ubuntu? Which part of OS is responsible for that window?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I don't really understand which feature of windows you are talking about. Please explain a bit better (maybe using screenshots) what exactly you want to archieve.

Comment: Screenshot added :)

Comment: Ah okey so you mean in general in Windows File Explorer it is possible to add/move/copy files even though the file explorer only opened because of a dialogue such as "Open" or "Save". I don't know how this is handled in Ubuntu but I'm pretty sure there's a filebrowser which supports this too